# Как вызывать функцию, имея строку?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Пишу бота на python-telegram-bot, хочу, чтобы данные для вывода сообщений после нажатия пользователем кнопок брались из базы данных. Не могу понять как правильно вставлять параметр reply_markup в метод send_message. В зависимости от нажатой кнопки, циклом проверяю есть ли такая кнопка в словаре кнопок, передаю key в базу данных и получаю нужную клавиатуру. Без поднятия данных из БД метод выглядит так:

```
context.bot.send_message(
    chat_id=chat_id,
    text=text,
    reply_markup=get_instruction(),
)
```

Из БД получаю строку get_instruction(), и при постановке в параметр, конечно же, выполняется с ошибкой.
Получилось сделать только вот таким образом:

```
def do_echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    text = update.message.text
    for k, value in TITLES.items():
        if text in value:
            key = k
            data = db.get_text_buttons(key)
            print(data)
            markup = db.get_markup_buttons(key) # Получаем по ключу данные из БД
            markup2 = get_bd_parameters(markup)
            context.bot.send_message(
                chat_id=chat_id,
                text=data,
                parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN,
                reply_markup=markup2,
            )

def get_bd_parameters(markup):
    if markup == "get_instruction()":
        return get_instruction()
```

Но для каждой кнопки нужно будет в функции создавать проверку типа `if parameter == "parameter": return get_keyboard()`
Есть ли способы лаконично оформить этот код без кучи if'ов? Или есть ли способы вызывать функцию, имея строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу два решения, первое, создать словарь с ключом в виде строки и значением вызываемой функции

```py
def func1():
  print("func1")

def func2():
  print("func2")

funcs = {
  "func1": func1, # функция не вызывается
  "func2": func2,
}


markup = "func2"

funcs[markup]() # обратите внимание что вызов функции происходит именно тут
```

Вывод:

```
func2
```

Но, я бы предпочел в этом случае подумать и сделать ключи и хранение в базе более понятными для чтения вашего кода

Второй вариант использовать `exec`

```py
def func():
  print("Hello world")


exec("func()")
```

Вывод:

```
Hello world
```